# WPF GridView in ListView with CheckBox in header error

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, checkbox

I have problems to add a checkbox in the grid view header. When I add it appears like a ToString() of the checkbox.

My XAML is this:

```
<ListView  x:Name="grdLotes" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,20,0" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Lotes">
            <GridViewColumn Width="70">
                <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Número" Width="70"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Tipo" Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Comentario" Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Movimientos" Width="80"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This is what shows:
[image: View]

Any idea how to solve this?
I tried to add into `<GridViewColumn.Header>` but is the same

Comment: For me your code is working properly showing a CheckBox. Not able to replicate your scenario.

Comment: I tried with DataGrid and have the same problem